# Ошибка “vector subscript out of range” в цикле

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

[image: код[1]]

При компиляции (1) выдает (2). Что делать? Как бороться?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете применять оператор индексирования к вектору, который еще не имеет элементов.

Поэтому вам следует написать перед циклами

```
cin >> str;
cin >> stb;

vect.resize(str, std::vector<int>(stb));
```

То есть сначала нужно создать элементы вектора, а затем лишь обращаться к ним по индексу.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант инициализации (при создании можешь размерность указать):

```
int a,b;
cin>>a>>b;
vector<vector <int> > mas(a,vector<int>(b));
size_t size = mas.size();
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    for_each(mas[i].begin(),mas[i].end(),[](int& k){cin>>k;});
}
```